If you had it to do over again, would you marry her again? | Is "....had IT to do over...." the same as "....had to do IT over..."?
On TV, a presenter is asking a man questions about the vasectomy he had had before, and now wants reversed. Here are two seperate sentences of the TV presenter:
Sentence 1: If you had IT to do over again would you marry her again? Get out of my family tree (See: 19:34-19:38).
Sentence 2: And do you think that if you had THAT to do over again, you'd still get it reversed? Get out of my family tree (See: 19:40-19:55)
The structure which was used by the presenter two times "...had it to do..." and "...had that to do..." caught my attention. I have never heard it used this way.
Is it simply another version of the modal (have to) as in "If you had to do it/that over again..."?

The presenter is asking the guy whether he would marry the woman who's now his wife, if he went back in time and relived the situation that led him to marry her. He's not asking if the guy whether he'd have the vasectomy again if he could go back. Anyway, he actually says If you had to over again...? - he's just slurring over the cumbersome phrasing of If you had to do it all over again...? It's speech in a fast-flowing discussion, not textbook English.

@FumbleFingers, I have watched the whole show. And the presenter is asking if he would have reversed the vasectomy again, if he had been given the change again.  Just watch (19:40-19:55) if you want to be sure.

I don't have time for all that. But the specific words you're asking about aren't "proper English". It's rapid casual speech with "deletions". And I think the only reason you're hearing that there is because he's saying hat instead of had - it's perfectly normal for many native Anglophones to enunciate had and have as hat and haff when to have [to do something] is used to mean be obliged to [do it].

...well, I've ended being pinged by Andy's comment, so I did listen to it again. At 19:35 the presenter asks the guy If you HAT to over again... regarding whether he would marry his wife. In that question, HAT is an emphatic version of HAD implying if it was necessary to make the choice again. Then at 19:52 (after introducing the vasectomy reversal) he asks If you had THAT to do over again... - asking the guy whether he would reverse the vasectomy again. Where THAT is stressed to contrast it with the previous question about getting married. I only heard the first one before.

Dr Phil is a Southern American speaker, I hear that with a "d" sound-maybe it's even hat –so it becomes: "And do you think dat [slight pause] ..if..if.. you had dat to do over again, you'd still get it [the vasectomy] reversed?"

@Mari-LouA: There are certainly no /d/'s in either of the two that's when he says And do you think that [slight pause] ..if..if.. you had THAT to do over again...

Fine @FumbleFingers my hearing's not perfect, I even conceded it might be "hat". Now you're saying it's "that" I'm not arguing with you, so why are retaliating? I do think that momentary pause affects the choice of words the TV Dr. says though.

@Mari-LouA: Sorry. I guess I'm a bit tetchy because I thought the original question (without a specific link to the second of two very similar questions) was badly presented. I ended up originally listening to only the first. And I still don't really understand how the OP could have passed over the first (potentially challenging for nns), yet seek clarification for the second, which seems relatively straightforward. The pause on the second seems 100% natural to me, because the presenter feels slightly awkward about the switch from repeat marrying to repeat vasectomy reversal.

Yes, "have it to do over again" is a common idiomatic pattern. I couldn't find a dictionary entry addressing it directly (though some about "over again" and so forth are helpful), but here's an ngram showing it's at least reasonably similar in frequency to the phrase "do it over again." It's usually used in a conditional, as here, meaning "if you somehow magically were given the opportunity to face this choice again, would you make the same choice?" So "have" is used here less about compulsion (you "have to" redo it) and more about possession/opportunity (you "have the chance to" redo it). Note FumbleFingers' comments about the careless spoken delivery.

I don't think the guy is saying either had that or had it [to over again]... It's just an example of if you had to being enunciated as if you HAT to... See this earlier ELL question, and this reddit page.

@FumbleFingers I'm not listening on the best of speakers right now, but it sounds to me like "If you had't to do over again"; that is, there's an understood and ellided "it," and I think I can just make out a vestigial hint of it.

Well, if that's what you [think you] hear, I won't keep arguing. But imho it's not natural to say it there (or that, which OP apparently hears), whereas pronouncing had as  hat in such contexts is extremely common.

...I just listened to more of the clip. The presenter asks two questions in a similar way, and I stopped after hearing the first one. The second one has a very emphatic If you had THAT to do over again... - emphatic because he's now asking about the vasectomy reversal, rather than marrying the current wife. I don't really see why anyone (even a non-native) would have trouble hearing that, since it's very heavily stressed (perfectly naturally, given the context and the specific subject matter! :) But have an upvote for standing your ground!

@FumbleFingers Oh, I'd say that including the "it" is much more idiomatic than leaving it out, and ngrams seems to agree. I threw "that" into the ngram as well and it ranks rather low, but it's a reasonable extension of "it."

NGrams is irrelevant to this specific context, where the entire reason for that heavy stress on that is because he's just asked whether the guy would do something else again, so it's a this and that contrast. Accentuated by the fact that the second question (Would you make the same vasectomy choice?) is far more "delicate" than the first question (Would you marry your wife again?).

It's not quasi-modal had to expressing obligation but lexical "have" (as in "to have a choice") in an irrealis backshift.
